# How can I keep html content history to make back button work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Good day!

I am building a mobile app.  I have index.html "screen A" which onSubmit calls javascript function:

```
$.get(myRemoteURL, function(data) {
document.open();
document.write(data);
document.close();
}, "text");
```

which then overwrites page with new content "screen B" obtained from making webservice RQ.  This content is jquery mobile content that I build programmatically in my Java tags with all the "divs" and "page" elements required for mobile view.

I then make another webservice RQ and again repeat similar javascript function call to replace with new jquery mobile content "screen C" with new data obtained from that webservice RQ.

The problem: I cannot find a way to make a "back" button work properly from "screen C" to "screen B".  I am sort of able to go back from "screen B" to "screen A" by using window.history.go(-2) (window.history.length said 7 but why exactly -2 works to get back to index.html I have no idea).

The big problem is I can't get back from "screen C" to "screen B".  I am trying to get to HTML content that I replaced from content I replaced it with.  I tried to use JSON localStorage to store content of "screen B" in a variable so I can replace content of "screen C" with stored content of "screen B", but that didn't work.  I also got an error

```
"Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-402" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space"
```

When trying to store content of "screen B" in JSON localStorage - the data obtained from webservice RQ and mobile content is in the 1-2MB range.

Please, could somebody suggest a way to implement a "back" button mechanism so I can go back from "screen C" to "screen B"?  Should I use cookies?  Or is there a way to retain "screen B" content in history?

ADDED:

As requested.  I add more information about "screen B" to C transition.  In "screen B" I have mobile pages ant the program logic either switches between those pages within "screen B" or makes new webservice RQ to switch to "screen C".  The way I switch to "screen C" is similar as from index.html to "screen B", namely, I programmatically build GET parameters using in my tag class (which builds jquery-mobile content for "screen B") those parameters I then use to make webservice RQ to obtain data for "screen C".  In "screen B" it is:

```
<a href="" onClick="switchToScreenC(_hidden_id_value, urlForScreenC)">Select</a>
```

The _hidden_id_value I have are hidden input fields I use to store values required to make webservice RQ to obtain data for "screen C".

Then my javascript:

```
urlForScreenC = urlForScreenC + "?parameter=" + $("#" + _hidden_id_value).val();

$.get(urlForScreenC, function(data) {
document.open();
document.write(data);
document.close();
}, "text");
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Victor.

Comment: You should add more info about the way you overwrite pages B and C after your webservices requests

Comment: are you building hybrid app ?

Comment: Just use `location = myRemoteURL` instead of bothering with Ajax in the first place.

Comment: Yes, this is a hybrid app.

Comment: Alternatively, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: Quentin: I originally used window.location.href = myRemoteURL but the problem was that there was a brief 2 or more second delay when switching to another screen.  In those situations the wait spinner disappeared but for brief seconds screen didn't switch.  With ajax I have wait message showing (and stopping) precisely at the moment when page switches to new screen (hope that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention that using localStorage actually does work.  According to docs localStorage allows at least 5MB.  I used the largest test of data from webservice response and data got stored and retrieved successfully:

Store:

```
localStorage.setItem("screenB", document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

Retrieve:

```
function goBackToScreenB()
{
document.open();
document.write(localStorage.getItem("screenB"));
document.close();
}
```

So, "Screen C" calls goBackToScreenB() and this stored content appears successfully as though "back" button was pressed.

I also looked at history.pushState() as one of the commentators suggests from developermozilla site, however the max content size allowed for history.pushState() seems to only allow max 640K characters and they recommend using localStorage as an alternative anyways.

Hopefully this solution would help somebody else as technique of implementing "back" button feature with large HTML content.

Thanks,
Victor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may be helpful to you:

```
 history.forward();
```